# How to create namespace using StaxEventItemWriter rootElementAttribs

Tags: spring-batch

I'm using Spring Batch StaxEventItemWriter and Jaxb2Marshaller to create an XML file; the final file includes the namespace as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<product-lists 
xmlns="http://www.demandware.com/xml/impex/productlist/2009-10-28">
<product-list list-id="14d3a4eb97570219f2bd26525e">
<owner customer-no="00002004">
<email>c@j9.com</email>
</owner>
<type>wish_list</type>
<public>false</public>
</product-list>
</product-lists>
```

I am getting the following error when creating a namespace attribute using the StaxEventItemWriter:

```
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: xmlns has been already bound to . Rebinding it to http://www.demandware.com/xml/impex/productlist/2009-10-28 is an error
    at com.sun.xml.internal.stream.writers.XMLStreamWriterImpl.writeDefaultNamespace(XMLStreamWriterImpl.java:786)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.stream.writers.XMLStreamWriterImpl.writeNamespace(XMLStreamWriterImpl.java:1003)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.stream.writers.XMLEventWriterImpl.add(XMLEventWriterImpl.java:127)
```

Code of the item writer:

```
@Bean(destroyMethod = "")
public ItemWriter<ProductList> xmlWriter() 
   StaxEventItemWriter<ProductList> xmlFileWriter = new StaxEventItemWriter<>();
   HashMap<String, String> rootElementAttribs = new HashMap<String, String>();
   String exportFilePath = "./XXX_List_XXX_" + FeedBatchUtil.getCurrentTimeStamp().replace(":", "").replace(".", "_") + ".xml";
   /* Doen not Work*/
   rootElementAttribs.put("xmlns", "http://www.demandware.com/xml/impex/productlist/2009-10-28");
   /*Works*/
   //rootElementAttribs.put("xmlns:ns1", "http://www.demandware.com/xml/impex/productlist/2009-10-28");
   xmlFileWriter.setResource(new FileSystemResource(exportFilePath));
   xmlFileWriter.setRootTagName("product-lists");
   xmlFileWriter.setRootElementAttributes(rootElementAttribs);
   Jaxb2Marshaller empMarshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
   empMarshaller.setClassesToBeBound(ProductList.class);
   xmlFileWriter.setShouldDeleteIfEmpty(true);
   xmlFileWriter.setMarshaller(empMarshaller);
   return xmlFileWriter;
}
```

Comment: the comment `/*Works*/` in your code implies you have a working solution. Is that correct? Are you still having the issue even with `//rootElementAttribs.put("xmlns:ns1", "http://www.demandware.com/xml/impex/productlist/2009-10-28");` ?

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine rootElementAttribs.put("xmlns:ns1", "http://www.demandware.com/xml/impex/productlist/2009-10-28"); works -- rootElementAttribs.put("xmlns", "http://www.demandware.com/xml/impex/productlist/2009-10-28"); The namescape format does not works. It gives an exception -> xmlns has been already bound to . Rebinding it to http://www.demandware.com/xml/impex/productlist/2009-10-28 is an error

Comment: I want the namespace value to be as follows --> <product-lists
 xmlns="http://www.demandware.com/xml/impex/productlist/2009-10-28">

Answer (score 1):

> I want the namespace value to be as follows  `<product-lists xmlns="demandware.com/xml/impex/productlist/2009-10-28">`

Here is an example:

```
StaxEventItemWriter<ProductList> staxEventItemWriter = new StaxEventItemWriter<>();
staxEventItemWriter.setResource(new FileSystemResource("test.xml"));
HashMap<String, String> rootElementAttribs = new HashMap<String, String>();
rootElementAttribs.put("xmlns", "demandware.com/xml/impex/productlist/2009-10-28");
staxEventItemWriter.setRootTagName("product-lists");
staxEventItemWriter.setRootElementAttributes(rootElementAttribs);
Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
marshaller.setClassesToBeBound(ProductList.class);
staxEventItemWriter.setMarshaller(marshaller);
staxEventItemWriter.afterPropertiesSet();

staxEventItemWriter.open(new ExecutionContext());
staxEventItemWriter.write(Arrays.asList(new ProductList()));
staxEventItemWriter.close();
```

The class `ProductList` is defined as follows:

```
@XmlRootElement
private static class ProductList {
    // TODO add your fields as required
}
```

The previous sample generates a `test.xml` file having the namespace as you are looking for:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<product-lists xmlns="demandware.com/xml/impex/productlist/2009-10-28">
    <productList/>
</product-lists>
```

Hope this helps.